# Does $\|A\|$ or $-\|A\|$ belongs to $\sigma(A)$ for a normal operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, normal-operator

For a normal operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $H$, I know that spectral radius $r(A)=\|A\|$. The question says is it true that either $\|A\|$ or $-\|A\|$ belongs to spectrum $\sigma(A)$?

I have started this way. We can obtain $\lambda_n \in \sigma(A)$ such that $\lvert\lambda_n\rvert \to \|A\|$. For a moment I thought I am through as this will imply $\lambda_n \to \|A\|$ and since $\sigma(A)$ is closed, $\|A\| \in \sigma(A)$. But soon I realised my mistake. But now I am stuck on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The spectrum of a normal operator need not be real. Try to look for a counter-example among (low dimensional) matrices.

Comment: I think I got it. I considered $A(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)=(\alpha_2, - \alpha_1)$. The only eigenvalues are $i,-i$ and $\|A\|=1$. $A$ is also normal.

Comment: You've got it. And if you allow for complex matrices then $A=(i)$ (1 by 1 matrix) is also an example.

Comment: But I think we can find λ∈σ(A) such that |λ|=‖A‖. Can you check my argument for correctness. We can find sequence λn∈σ(A) such that |λn|→‖A‖. Then λn has a convergent subsequence say  
$\hat{\lambda_n}$
  converging to say a∈σ(A). This gives | $\hat{\lambda_n}$
 |→|a|. This implies |a|=‖A‖, by uniqueness of limits.

Comment: @Believer Yes that is perfectly ok. As soon as you know that $r(A)=\|A\|$ then compactness of the spectrum gives the result through your argument.